# sssd (2.0.0, CentOS 8) with old tls 1.0 only ldap

Tags: ssl, ldap, sssd

I can't connect sssd (2.0.0, CentOS 8) with old tls 1.0 only ldap (MacOS X 10.6 server).

Working, so this should be possible:

`openssl s_client -connect snow.cologne.intradesys.com:ldaps -tls1`

In /etc/openldap/ldap.conf i have the option to set `TLS_PROTOCOL_MIN 3.1` (= TLS 1.0)

But looking at:
`man sssd-ldap`
i have a lot of ldap_tls_... parameters, but non to downgrade to TLS 1.0

So i get `/var/log/sssd/sssd_default.log:`

`/var/log/sssd/sssd_default.log[sss_ldap_init_sys_connect_done] (0x0020): ldap_install_tls failed: [Connect error] [error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found another and more appropriate solution with the same effect.

```
update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY
systemctl restart sssd
```

Job done.